# react-native 0.42 Expected array with count 16

Tags: react-native

After upgrading to React Native 0.42 in order to get `FlatList` support, My app no longer runs properly. I get the following error:
[image]

The only related information I could find was [this github issue](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/550) for `react-navigation` a package which I am **not** using.

Can anyone suggest a way to debug this issue, or any fix to get rid of it.

I have tried the usual deleting `node_modules` and re-installing.

**UPDATE**

I have isolated the issue to the `Navigator` component, As I stop receiving this error if I simply render the initial route without the Navigator

But a new app created with `react-native init` didn't have any trouble rendering a `Navigator`

very much at a loss as to how to procede. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out I simply forgot to clear the `build` directory under `ios`, which resulted in running new Javascript on an old native build. Removing this showed me merge conflicts in the ios files.

Comment: I've removed the build, re-installed node_modules and it's not working.
Weird thing is that in a complete brand new project works!! 
What worked for me was downgraded to 0.41

Answer (score 0):

For me was not enough to remove the `ios/build folder` what I worked was to execute `react-native upgrade` which re-creates the bundle of the dependencies at the mentioned folder